# how to get elements in separated rows in html table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, bootstrap-4

Hey i am fetching data from excel file but all the data is returning in only one row box this is my html code

```
{% block body %}

# i am using bootstrap table class
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Pensioner name</th>
              <th scope="col">cnic</th>
              <th scope="col">mobile</th>
              <th scope="col">wallet</th>


            </tr>
          </thead>

            <tr>
                {% if 'm1' %}
                <td><h6 >{{ m1 }}</h6></td>
                {% endif %}

                {% if 'm2' %}
                <td><h6 >{{ m2 }}</h6></td>
                {% endif %}
                {% if 'm3' %}
                <td><h6 >{{ m3 }}</h6></td>
                {% endif %}
                {% if 'm4' %}
                <td><h6 >{{ m4 }}</h6></td>
                {% endif %}
          </tr>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

this is my output[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbZNk.png)

i want data into separate rows boxes now it looks to messy please help

Answer (score 0):

To create a new row you would need to add a new `<tr>` element for each row.

Here is a working example

```css
table,
tr,
th,
td {
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Job Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>James</td>
      <td>Matman</td>
      <td>Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The</td>
      <td>Tick</td>
      <td>Crimefighter Sorta</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Each `<tr>` element inside the `<tbody>` element creates a new row.

Comment: sorry but this still doesnt work please consider that these 'm' variables contains multiple  rows not single

Comment: Oh I see. I though you were asking about how to structure the HTML because of the tags of the question. I suggest you add all the tags related to the technology your question is about.